# Grep command to get 2 character strings that start or end with a vowel

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, grep

How can I ignore any 2 letter words in a text file that do not begin or end with a vowel?

I have tried several attempts and find myself stuck. This attempt below was aimed at finding a 2 letter word that started or ended with a vowel.

```
 grep -Eio '\^[aeiou]{2\}|[aeiou]${2\}\b'
```

Comment: Please post some example data with expected results,

Comment: The `\^` notation is dubious; it looks for a literal caret in the data.  It isn't clear how that is related to the 2-letter word finding in the rest of the question.  The title says '2 character strings'; the body says '2 letter words'.  Those are quite different.  Your requirements are very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You have very generously sprinkled backslashes in places where they are not useful or required. *Generally* with `grep -E`, some characters have a "magical" meaning when used *without* a backslash, and a backslash is required when you need to match the character itself.  So for example, `^` marks the beginning of a line, and `{` specifies the beginning of a repetition specification; and `\^` and `\{` match a literal caret and opening curly brace, respectively.

Though there are some cases where this isn't true -- `<` and `>` match literally, and `\<` and `\>` match word boundaries ... which is probably exactly what we need here.

So I'm guessing you are looking for

```
grep -Eio '\<[^aeiou]{2}\>' file
```

which looks for two adjacent characters which are between word boundaries, where neither character can be a vowel.

As an aside, there is no way for `${2}` to do anything useful; the end of line cannot be followed by anything, ever, because `grep` only examines a single line at a time.